# Base64 encode/decode without padding on golang ( appengine )

Tags: google-app-engine, go, encoding, base64

There's a way to encode/decode a string to/from Base64 without having the padding at the end? I mean the '==' ending.

I'm using `base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString` to encode and it works perfectly but I didn't see a way to decide to not use the padding at the end ( like on java ).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go1.5 will have a [`WithPadding`](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/#Encoding.WithPadding) option on `Encoding`.

This also will add 2 pre-defined encodings, [`RawStdEncoding`, and `RawURLEncoding`](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/#pkg-variables), which will have no padding.

Though since you're on app-engine, and won't have access to Go1.5 for a while, you can make some helper function to add and remove the padding as needed.

Here is an example to encode and decode strings. If you need, it could easily be adapted to work more efficiently using `[]byte`.

```
func base64EncodeStripped(s string) string {
    encoded := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(s))
    return strings.TrimRight(encoded, "=")
}

func base64DecodeStripped(s string) (string, error) {
    if i := len(s) % 4; i != 0 {
        s += strings.Repeat("=", 4-i)
    }
    decoded, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(s)
    return string(decoded), err
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Simply,

use `base64.RawStdEncoding.EncodeToString` instead of `base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString`

OR else

use `base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString` instead of `base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString`.

[Reference: see source-code comments Line 94 to 110](https://golang.org/src/encoding/base64/base64.go?s=3207:3400#L93):

```
// RawURLEncoding is the unpadded alternate base64 encoding defined in RFC 4648.
// It is typically used in URLs and file names.
// This is the same as URLEncoding but omits padding characters.
```

Comment: Note that if the padding anyway was added then the RawURLEncoding will fail to decode. So to make it safe you have to remove the padding e.g. `base64.RawURLEncoding.DecodeString(strings.TrimRight(encryptedPrice, "="))`

Answer (score 0):

To Encode:

```
str := "encode this"
encodedStr := base64.StdEncoding.
    WithPadding(base64.NoPadding).
    EncodeToString([]byte(str))

fmt.Println(encodedStr)
```

To Decode:

```
data, err := base64.
    StdEncoding.WithPadding(base64.NoPadding).
    DecodeString(encodedStr)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

fmt.Println(string(data))
```

Go Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/TAZgLMSSe-K

Answer (score 0):

To omit padding characters for base64 encoding in golang and make the result url safe, you can use

```
value := base64.RawURLEncoding.EncodeToString(bytes)
```

> RawURLEncoding is the unpadded alternate base64 encoding defined in RFC 4648. It is typically used in URLs and file names. This is the same as URLEncoding but omits padding characters.

https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/base64